# Jetty Service on Windows Server 2008 using Procrun: Missing service ImageFile

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, jetty

Xe want to run Jetty as a service on a Windows 2008 Server Virtual Machine. Therefore, I configured Jetty as a Windows Service using Apacke Procrun, following this short description: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094429/running-jetty-7-as-windows-service

Locally on a Windows 7 machine with admin rights, everything works like a charm. Unfortunately, when testing the service with JettyService.exe //TS on the VM, I get the following error:
-Service "JettyService" is missing the ImageFile [error] ServiceStart returned 1

Further observations: 
-The service is shown in Windows' list of services. When trying to start it, I get a "File not found" error.
-The Procrun configuration GUI doesn't show me any service details, although it did on my local version. It seems as if the service just doesn't exist. Anyway, when trying to define the same service again, I get a message that a service has already been defined.

Unfortunately, there don't seem to be too many people encountering this problem. Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated! Could this be about service permissions?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, just close quotes when referring to the target as described on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094429/running-jetty-7-as-windows-service

i.e.

```
bin\JettyService //IS//JettyService --DisplayName="Jetty Service" --Install="C:\java\jetty\jetty-distribution-7.4.2.v20110526\bin\JettyService.exe"
```